# AWS beanstalk cgi-bin permissions

Tags: linux, perl, cgi, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cgi-bin

I am having an issue with aws's beanstalk and running my webapp.

I have set everything up the same way as my last hosting account but I am getting a permissions error in the cgi-bin in var/www/cgi-bin/server.pl when trying to run the script.

There must be something somewhere that i need to change to run this.

I have set the permissions to 755 to cgi-bin and sever.pl

and in the httpd.conf i added

Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl

so it looks like this

```
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
AllowOverride None
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

i have the close Directory at the end it just isnt showing up here

is there anything else you can see I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have had to add this line in order to get scripts to work in Apache:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
```